# batch showing text while executing command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, system, profile

Im trying to figure out if i can display something like "Please wait while we finish your setup" while also executing a command without showing the processing of the command in a batch file. For ex. **Systeminfo** it has to load some things before displaying the results, but i dont want it to show that stuff like "Loading network card information" or "Loading Hotfix Information" i only want it to display the results.

This is all that i can come up with but hasnt worked.

```
@echo off
color a
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Please wait...
@systeminfo
pause >nul
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command on XP:

```
systeminfo 2>nul
```

Comment: Doesn't work, because the respective messages are not written to STDERR.

Comment: You're right. I just checked on XP and it does work there. It doesn't on Windows 7, though.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you/d have to try

```
START /wait /min "" CMD /c systeminfo ^>sysinfo.txt
```

which should output the SYSINFO data to sysinfo.bat

There are plenty of references to how to run this silently if you so wish. As it stands, a minimised window will be created while the `SYSINFO` is executed.